# nextcord py parameter on_raw_message_delete

Tags: python, parameters, discord.py, nextcord

I use on_raw_message_delete and i want to print the name of the person who deleted the message.
I can print the deleted message and user who writed the message but I don't know how to print the name of the person who deleted the deleted message.

```
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_raw_message_delete(self, payload):
    channel = self.bot.get_channel(channel_id)
    embed = nextcord.Embed(title="message deleted",
    description=f"Message deleted in <#{payload.cached_message.channel.id}>\n Message deleted by {payload.name}")
```

Comment: What documentation have you looked at for the payload? Is there anything in there that might help?

Comment: @TheFungusAmongUs i looked at this site https://docs.nextcord.dev/en/stable/api.html#nextcord.on_raw_message_delete

Comment: You need to check the audit logs for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not part of the message delete payload, so you'll need to check the audit logs.

You also may want to check the date of the entry since a user deleting their own message is not logged to audit logs.

```py
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_message_delete(self, message: nextcord.Message):
    async for entry in message.guild.audit_logs(action=nextcord.AuditLogAction.message_delete, limit=1):
        log = entry
    # if deleted more than a second ago, use the author instead
    deleter = log.user if (datetime.now() - log.created_at).seconds > 1 else message.author
```

Note that this may be unreliable if you have messages deleted frequently in your guild.

This is untested, but you can modify as needed.